# Typescript Importing Problem on Cropperjs library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cropperjs

I am using the react-cropper library.

My workflow requires me to create a custom typescript definition file.

I create a file namely "react-cropper.d.ts" inside root react folder typings-custom and I also registered into ts.config as follow:

```
 "include": [
    "src",
    "./typings-custom/**/*.ts"
  ]
```

`import * as cropperjs from 'cropperjs';`

This is is just working fine with this statement.

[image: Project 1]

I create another project and use the same library with the same method. But, this time to make it work, I have to

`import * as cropperjs from 'cropperjs/index';`

[image: Project 2]

Today, I create another project with the same abovementioned method. But, unfortunately., both the above solution won't work anymore. I try the absolute path or relative path. Both are not working either.

[image: Project 3]

*** Note: project 1 or 2 is still running okay on the same developing machine.

I think the issue is referencing the file.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using the official types `@types/react-cropper`?

Comment: the default @types/react-cropper accepts "string" but what ref I am returning is  "RefObject<ReactCropper>". => I can change on the node-modules but it is not the right way to do so. So, I create custom type.

Comment: original: export interface ReactCropperProps extends cropperjs.CropperOptions, Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLImageElement>, 'data' | 'ref'> {
      ref?: string | ((cropper: null | ReactCropper) => any);
  } new: export interface ReactCropperProps extends cropperjs.CropperOptions, Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLImageElement>, 'data' | 'ref'> {
      ref?: string | React.RefObject<Cropper> | ((cropper: null | ReactCropper) => any);
  }

Comment: Using @types/react-cropper by modifiying some code is a solution. but it is not good